# SQL: duplicating rows with an additional running sequence field

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to create a select statement to duplicate each unique row (by 'location' field) by 361 times (0 to 360). An additional column is also created showing the sequence (0 to 360). The purpose of this is to calculate the coordinates around each of the lat & long using the radius and degree fields to render it as a circle within Tableau.

This is the original sample table.

[image]

This is the final desired output.

[image]

Can anyone help?

sample data in comma delimited~

```
Location,Radius,Latitude,Longitude
A,500,31.4799,88.38783
B,1000,35.580941,77.01125
C,800,37.492528,88.797115
```

**EDIT**: There are 50 plus rows in the original table.

Comment: which database?

Comment: it's in vertica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Vertica has the equivalent of Postgres's `generate_series()`.  You can mock it, if you have a table with at least 361 rows:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over () - 1 as n
      from (select s.* from sample s limit 361) s
     )
select s.*, n.n as degress
from sample s cross join
     n;
```

In Vertica, `order by` is optional for the `row_number()` function.

Comment: oh dear, the problem is that I only have 50 plus rows in the table~ any alternatives in ur opinion?

Comment: Ah, replacing the 'sample' table in the 3rd line with any other table with more than 360 rows will remove the reliance on the original table rows. Will mark ur answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also abuse `time series` in Vertica to generate a sequence without needing any tables at all:

```
with mydegrees as (
    SELECT extract( epoch from slice_time - to_timestamp(0) ) Degree
    from ( select to_timestamp(0) ts 
           union all
           select to_timestamp(0) + interval '360 seconds' ) x   
    TIMESERIES slice_time AS '1 second' OVER (ORDER BY ts)
) 
select t.*, d.Degree
from mytable t cross join 
     mydegrees d;
```

Basically we just set a start/to timestamp for 0 to 360 seconds, then we extract the 'seconds since epoch 0' for each time slice (using a 1 second time slice).